# Flask redirect not happening in browser when trigger by JS callback function

Tags: javascript, flask

I have a flask app with a button's onClick callback that is handled by javascript. The JS function calls an endpoint of the flask app (after collecting all the necessary data for the request from DOM elements) - it's not tied to a form. Within the flask endpoint, it redirects to another page. Looking in network tab, the request to `flask_endpoint` does not return a response because of the redirection. Response of request says `Failed to load response data: No content available because the request was redirected`. However, in the network tab, a separate request of the redirected route is created and the template is in the response of this request. But, it does not redirect the actual browser route to that response. Can someone explain why?

Javascript:

```
$('#add-button').click(callback)
async function callback(e) {
  await axios.post(`/some_flask_endpoint`, {
    ...request_body...
  });
}
```

Flask endpoint:

```
@app.route('/some_flask_endpoint', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def save_something():
  # some logic...
  return redirect('redirect_to_some_url')
```

Answer (score 0):

1. It is obvious that you are requesting on an endpoint "/some_flask_endpoint" but you redirect the request to 'redirect_to_some_url'.
2. JS you show does not appear to redirect the browser to the new endpoint.

Back to your "questions",
if you are questioning the `Fail to load`, it just tells you that the endpoint does not have any actual responses because it is a redirect.
If you are questioning about nothing happened in the browser after the redirect, it is because the js has responsibility on how to handle the response. If you do not redirect the browser, the browser stays.